# Logback Spring - Change log levels during runtime using an external yaml file outside of the jar

Tags: java, logging, logback, spring-logback

Inside of my logback-spring.xml file, I am able to change the log levels, and it's able to autodetect changes when I include auto scan. Looks like this:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
```

However, I want to keep all of my log levels in an external yaml configuration file and I don't want to have to restart the server to detect those changes. Is there a way to use an external yaml file to define log levels and use logback autoscan? Or should I be looking at a completely different way of going about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in application.yml, try adding the following settings

```
spring:
  logging:
    level:
      org.springframework.web: DEBUG
      com.company.package: DEBUG
```

You can also specify pattern if you like.